# read csv file without header lines in python

Tags: csv, python-2.7, import

I need to read a tab delimited csv file without the 11 header lines as shown below. How can I do this in python?

```
START:  21.09.2011  11:24:12

TIME STEP:
100 = 10s

VOLTAGE RANGE:
CH1:  255 = 3V  CH3:  255 = 30V
CH2:  255 = 30V CH4:  255 = 30V

N   CH1 Time/s  CH1/V   CH2/V   CH3/V   CH4/V

0   137 0,00    1,612   0,000   0,000   0,000
1   137 0,10    1,612   0,000   0,000   0,000
2   137 0,20    1,612   0,000   0,000   0,000
3   131 0,30    1,541   0,000   0,000   0,000
...
```

Thanks a lot
Otto

Comment: Note that the best way to read the file depends on what you're doing with it, because that affects which library you should use.  A simple row-based action?  Then `csv` will be fine.  More complicated actions move you through `numpy` toward `pandas`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
import csv
import itertools

with open('1.csv') as f:
    lines = itertools.islice(f, 11, None) # skip 11 lines, similar to [11:]
    reader = csv.reader(lines)
    for row in reader:
        ... Do whatever you want with row ..
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of next -> to skip

**Code :**

```
import csv

with open('1.csv') as f:
    csv_rd = csv.reader(f)
    next(csv_rd)

    for row in csv_rd:
        print(row)
```