# Python IndexError: list index out of range large file

Tags: python-3.x, indexoutofboundsexception, large-files

I have a very large file `~40GB` and `674,877,098` lines I want to read and extract specific columns from. I can get about `3GB` of data transferred then I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Codes\Read_cat_write.py", line 44, in <module>
tid = int(columns[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Sample of data that is being read in.

```
1,100000000,100000000,39,2.704006988169216e15,310057,0
2,100000001,100000000,38,2.650346740514816e15,303904,0.01
3,100000002,100000000,37,2.136985003098112e15,245039,0.03
4,100000003,100000000,36,2.29479163101184e15,263134,0.05
5,100000004,100000000,35,1.834645477916672e15,210371,0.06
6,100000005,100000000,34,1.814063860416512e15,208011,0.08
7,100000006,100000000,33,1.808883592986624e15,207417,0.1
8,100000007,100000000,32,1.806241248575488e15,207114,0.12
9,100000008,100000000,31,1.651783621410816e15,189403,0.14
10,100000009,100000000,30,1.634821184946176e15,187458,0.16
```

Code

```
from itertools import islice
F = r'C:\Users\Outfiles\comp_cat_raw.txt'
w = open(r'C:\Users\Outfiles\comp_cat_3col.txt','a')


def filesave(TID,M,R):     
  X = str(TID)
  Y = str(M)
  Z = str(R) 
  w.write(X)
  w.write('\t')
  w.write(Y)
  w.write('\t')
  w.write(Z)
  w.write('\n')


N = 680000000
f = open(F)           #Opens file
f.readline()          # Strips Header
nlines = islice(f, N) #slices file to only read N lines

for line in nlines:                   
 if line !='':
  line = line.strip()         
  line = line.replace(',',' ') # Replace comma with space
  columns = line.split()       # Splits into column
  tid = int(columns[2])
  m = float(columns[4])       
  r = float(columns[6])              
  filesave(tid,m,r)

w.close()
```

I have looked at the file being read in at the point where the error occurs, but I don't see anything wrong with the file so I am at a loss as to the cause of this error.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are, there is some line with maybe one single comma in there, or none, or an empty line, whatever. Probably just put a try-except statement around the statement and catch the index error, probably printing out the line in question, and you should be done. Besides that, there are some things in your code, that might be worth to improve.

- Have a look at the `csv` module especially. It has some optimized C-code exactly for what you want to do, so it should be much faster. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364166/read-csv-file-without-header-lines-in-python) shows mainly how to write the iteration with `csv`.
- This whole slice construction seems to be superfluous. A simple `for line in f:` will do and is the most efficient way to handle this iteration.
- Use `line.split(',')` directly, instead of replacing them first with spaces.
- Use `with open(F) as f:` instead of calling close yourself. For this script it might make no difference, but this way you make sure, that you e.g. don't create open file handles in case of errors.

Comment: Another hint: If you're not purely doing it for the learning experience, and if you have to handle CSVs more often, you might also want to try https://code.google.com/p/csvfix/ , which is a really fast and versatile tool for these kind of simple CSV operations.